# inserting record while looping inside cursor

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, cursor

I am a beginner and I have this question. So I have a table:

**config_items:**

```
id | item_key            | item_alias |   
---|---------------------|------------|  
5  | folder1.Move.hasFile| hasFile    |
4  | folder1.Move        | Move       |    
3  | folder2.Move        | Move       |
2  | folder3.Move        | Move       |  
1  | folder4.Download    | Download   |
```

I want to take records which has .Move in its item_key. After I get those records, I want to add .hasFile on each of them and insert them into the table as a new record. But if that config_key already exists ( eg folder1.Move.hasFile) that should not be added on table. I have done following but it is giving me Primary Key violation error for id. Can someone explain me where I am doing it wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_hasFile(v_key IN config_items.item_key%TYPE)
AS 
BEGIN
    insert into config_items
            (id,
            item_key,
            item_alias)
            (select 
                (select max(id) from config_items)+1,
                 v_key,
                'hasFile'
            from 
                config_items
            where
                not exists(select * from config_items where v_key =item_key )
            );
END; 
/

DECLARE
CURSOR item_records_curr
IS
SELECT * from config_items
where item_key LIKE '%.Move';

v_item_key config_items.item_key%TYPE;
v_all_info item_records_curr%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
   OPEN item_records_curr;

   LOOP 
      FETCH item_records_curr into v_all_info;     
       v_item_key := v_all_info.item_key || '.hasFile';
       insert_hasFile(v_item_key);
      EXIT WHEN item_records_curr%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE item_records_curr;
END;
```

Comment: What columns does the PK contain? Only ID  or something else?

Comment: It's a bad idea use `max(id)`  to calculating unique value of primary key. You should use sequences - it's better way.

Comment: @Aleksej id is the PK. item_key has to be unique.

Comment: Your insert-select can insert more than one record at every call, but the max is only one value, so it will try to insert n records with the same id

Comment: @Aleksej even if I use rownum is it going to be same thing? select max(id) from config_items)+rownum

Comment: rownum should solve, but a sequence is the right way, as @Surename said

Comment: Have a look at [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606); it can help you in simplify your code.

Comment: @aleksej rownum also gave me error for item_key unique key violation. Will go through merge. Thanks..

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have at least Oracle 12c you could just make ID in your table declaration an identity field, such as ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY

That way you don't have to worry about trying to calculate that in the SP, and can let the system generate the key for that.

As described here. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109

Answer (score 0):

In your Procedure **insert_hasFile** you are fetching records from **config_items** table which will select multiple records with same value for ID column.

Try inserting single record through the Procedure using **DUAL** as below..

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_hasFile(v_key IN config_items.item_key%TYPE)
AS 
BEGIN
    insert into config_items
            (id,
             item_key,
             item_alias)
             (select 
                 (select max(id) from config_items)+1,
                  v_key,
                 'hasFile'
             from 
                 dual
             where
                 not exists(select * from config_items where v_key =item_key )
            ) ;
END;  
/`
```